# 'timestamp with time zone' literal cannot be generated for Local DateTime

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity, npgsql

I am using .Net 7 and Entity with a Postgres database.
The database provider is Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.

I am trying to seed some data that includes a UTC timestamp into my database. It is throwing the error:

```
Applying migration '20231016121421_AddData'.
    System.InvalidCastException: 'timestamp with time zone' literal cannot be generated for Local DateTime: a UTC DateTime is required
           at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.Mapping.NpgsqlTimestampTzTypeMapping.GenerateLiteralCore(Object value)
           ...
    'timestamp with time zone' literal cannot be generated for Local DateTime: a UTC DateTime is required
```

Here is my code, I have played about with different UTC formats but I just can't find the right match.

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
    {

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        // Database Tables
        public DbSet<DataTable> DataTable { get; set; }


        // Seed Database With Test Data
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            new DbInitializer(modelBuilder).Seed();
        }

    }
```

I think the error is the format of my UTC when I try to seed the database?

```
public class DbInitializer
    {
        private readonly ModelBuilder modelBuilder;

        public DbInitializer(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            this.modelBuilder = modelBuilder;
        }

        // Starter Data For the Test Database
        public void Seed()
        {
            var dataJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTable>>(File.ReadAllText(@".\Database\Seed_Data.json"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataTable>().HasData(dataJson);
        }
    }
```

Sample json data, with the UTC timestamps:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1f5ar5ty-6cc2-4054-b64e-bbc0dde5fg7b",
    "OrderDate": "2021-08-07T14:41:12.000000Z",
    "Product": "Apples",
  },
  {
    "Id": "ca5t10c0-756c-4b29-b16c-1389eb25b3a4",
    "OrderDate": "2021-08-07T14:41:12.000000Z",
    "Product": "Bananas"
  },
]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: not in front of pc, but, why parse a string to a date when you can just create a new Datetime object with the same values and `DateTimeKind` of type `UTC`? If I a missing something I apologize, but a hard coded string versus hard codes ints...give it a shot. If you really wanna stick with `Parse()` look at this method to help PostGres `SpecifyKind()`. good luck

Comment: so your call could be modified to be: `DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("2023-06-15T20:37:19.000000Z"), DateTimeKind.Utc);`...hope it helps,

Comment: DateTime.Parse will return local time if possible. You added Z to say its UTC but Parse will recalculate it to local timestamp. If you want to go by @SimonWilson advice don't add Z.  Or you will get you then local time reinterpreted as UTC and you will in almost all cases be a few hours off. Where does this literal come from feels weird to have that hard coded?  A `new DateTime(2023, 6, 15, 20, 37, 19, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` would be safe.

Comment: Oh `// Starter Data For the Test Database` if think i understood why its hardcoded.

Comment: Originally it was a json file I would import to seed the database. I got the postgres issues so I tried just doing it all in C# but got the same issues. The date is just what was in the json file.

Comment: I edited the code to show the json data and hence the date string

Comment: My second comment still stands as a solution @ScottishSmile. Simply iterate your json array and seed the db with `DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(jsonObject.OrderDate), DateTimeKind.Utc)`. Let me see if I still have Visual Studio installed and try give you a better solution later

Comment: The solution I came up with was to write a C# program that imported the JSON file and re-wrote the dates in C#'s Json UTC format. It worked after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be of use? (Been a while since I touched C#.)

```
class OrderData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}

class DataTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderData>>(File.ReadAllText(@".\seed.json"));
        var shapedOrders = orders.Select<DataTable>((order) =>
        {
            Id = order.Id;
            OrderDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(order.OrderDate), DateTimeKind.Utc);
            Product = order.Product;
        });
       

        new modelBuilder.Entity<DataTable>().HasData(shapedOrders);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work when OrderDate contains Timezone information as Parse will recalculate it to your local timezone. In the example its in the UTC timezone. If your local timezone is lets say UTC+2 you get a datetime 2 hours less and then just reinterpret that time to be UTC so effectively getting a Orderdate 2 hours to early. Simply call `ToUniversalTime()` on what Parse returns should calculate correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Simon, I did something similar but I re-wrote the new date to a new json file then imported that.